# JavaScript for .. in loop IE issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox, for-loop

I am trying to work with checkboxes with javascript. IE (using IE8) seems to have an issue with the code below. It works perfectly well in Firefox.

This is my sample html.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" />
<input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two" />
<input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" />
<input type="checkbox" name="four" id="four" />
<input type="checkbox" name="five" id="five" />
```

IE just disables the checkbox with id "one" without touching "five" and "three".

```
var all = new Array("one","two","three","four","five");
var some = new Array("one","five","three");

disableFew(some);

function disableFew(few){
    for (var i in all){
        document.getElementById(all[i]).disabled = false;
    }
    for (var j in few){
        if(document.getElementById(few[j]).nodeName == 'INPUT'){
            document.getElementById(few[j]).checked = false;
        }
        document.getElementById(few[j]).value = 'disabled';
        document.getElementById(few[j]).disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Any clues on what's going on? I am just a beginner in web development so I might be missing some nuances of IE/Firefox.

Will appreciate any help !

Comment: If you change the order of the element ids in your `some` array does it still do just the first one? (By the way, best practice on declaring arrays is to use array literal syntax: `var some = ["one","five","three"];` or `var some = [];` for an empty array.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: The behavior still remains the same, irrespective of the order. I call several functions on page load/some event. It looks like IE redraws (acts) only after the script handles it control. I still am trying to find a way to return contorl to IE after every function. Any ideas?

Comment: It's normal for all browsers (not just IE) to complete the current script before redrawing. I'm not sure what you mean by "after every function" given that you've only shown one function, but you can give control back to the browser to allow redraw by scheduling your functions via `setTimeout()` (with a short delay for each, say 10ms). I really don't understand why the above code doesn't work in IE8, but the redraw thing is a separate issue so you might like to post that part as a new question with more detail.

Comment: P.S. I don't have IE8, but your code worked fine in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/w4ssG/

Comment: @nnnnnn Apparently, IE does not understand `document.getElementById(few[j]).value = 'disabled';document.getElementById(few[j]).disabled = true;
` when few[j] is a select list element. I changed to jQuery and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using a regular `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) ...
for(var j=0; j<some.length; j++) ...
```

The `for..in` you're using will iterate other properties from the array prototype, not only your array indexes.

Also, I'd avoid using `all` as a variable name, maybe IE can get confused (it has its `document.all`). But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: That's strange. Unfortunately I can't test on IE right now, I'm on a mac. But here's a jsfiddle in case someone else wants to try: http://jsfiddle.net/GgHnG/

Comment: I call several functions on page load/some event. It looks like IE redraws (acts) only after the script handles it control. I still am trying to find a way to return contorl to IE after every function. Any ideas?